# next_is_valid() doesn't exist in flask-login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

[Flask-login doc](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) says we should validate next using `next_is_valid()`, but I can't find any such method:

> Warning: You MUST validate the value of the next parameter. If you do not, your application will be vulnerable to open redirects.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Here we use a class of some kind to represent and validate our
    # client-side form data. For example, WTForms is a library that will
    # handle this for us.
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Login and validate the user.
        login_user(user)

        flask.flash('Logged in successfully.')

        next = flask.request.args.get('next')
        if not next_is_valid(next):
            return flask.abort(400)

        return flask.redirect(next or flask.url_for('index'))
    return flask.render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Running this I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'next_is_valid' is not defined
```

And if I do:

```
from flask.ext.login import next_is_valid
>> ImportError: cannot import name next_is_valid
```

Where is the `next_is_valid()` function, and if it doesn't exist, how do I validate the `next` parameter?

Comment: It doesn't say you must validate `next` with `next_is_valid`. That is just an example function; you're right, it doesn't exist. You must decide if `next` if valid based on your own criteria. `next` is the url to redirect to on a successful login. Hope this helps some.

Comment: @bnjmn this should be added as an answer I think with some references ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't say you must validate `next` with `next_is_valid`, only that

> You MUST validate the value of the next parameter.

**`next_is_valid` is just an example function.**

You must determine if `next` is valid based on your own criteria. `next` is the url to redirect to on a successful login. If you have any permissions to apply or restrictions on your site this is where you would want to make sure they are enforced.

For example, a user could attempt to login with the request url `http://example.com/login?next=admin/delete/all/users`. If the login attempt was successful and the admin permission was not checked within your login function or on the endpoint itself, well, bad things could happen. It all depends on how you structure your application and control access to individual endpoints.

Comment: Does this mean however that if `http://example.com/admin/delete/all/users` _is_ protected by something like `@admin_required` – you don't have to have a check like `next_is_valid()`?

Comment: @qff Exactly. The check would be performed by the `@admin_required` decorator on the route.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the examples mentioned by other answers, next could also be next=malicioussite.url. If a malicious actor sent someone to your login link with next set to their malicious site, then after logging in the user could think they are still on your site, but instead have been directed somewhere dangerous. Make sure to validate next against redirecting to other websites.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30662563)